# How to find unicode characters U+80, U+9D and U+93 using regex or directly oracle database 11g

Tags: regex, for-loop, unicode, character

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EktNO.png)Respondent practiced with a lapsed social work credential from 9/1/17  9/18/17

the above text having some special character that i am unable to pull using the regex and how to remove these characters from database. while updating is giving null value dialog box

Comment: I don't see it, you seem to have successfully get rid of it by copy-pasting. It makes sense that there would be an en-dash (`–` U+2013) between the two dates. Encoded in UTF-8 that would be `0xE2 0x80 0x93`. Please confirm whether I'm guessing right.

Comment: Are you listing code points or bytes? If they are code points, you are listing control codes. You should tag your question to the language/database engine you are using, people uses tags to find questions to answer (there are too many questions to filter them from title)

Comment: see the image for more details